# Dúvida código MATLAB para Opencv C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, matlab

Boa noite pessoal!

Gostaria de uma ajuda em relação a passar um código que está em matlab para opencv c++. Estou tentando fazer algumas operações com os canais rgb, porém, o valor do thresh não esta sendo o mesmo - estou passando a mesma imagem. Alguém, por gentileza, poderia me ajudar?

MATLAB

```
im = imread('1.png');

[m,n,p] = size(im);

R=im(:, :, 1);
G=im(:, :, 2);
B=im(:, :, 3);

thresh=0;

for j=1:n
    for i=1:m
        thresh = thresh + double((1.262*G(i,j))-(0.884*R(i,j))-(0.311*B(i,j)));
    end
end
```

C++

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(){
    Mat img = imread("1.png", IMREAD_COLOR); 
    int thresh = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j <= img.cols; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i <= img.rows; i++){
            Vec3b color = img.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
            uchar a = color.val[0], b = color.val[1], c = color.val[2];
            thresh += double((1.262*b)-(0.884*c)-(0.311*a));
        }
    }
    
    cout << thresh;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ` img.cols` e ` img.rows` são o número de colunas e linhas? Se for então a comparação nos dois loops provavelmente deveria ser `<` ao invés de `<=`.

Comment: ` int thresh = 0;` não deveria ser ` double thresh = 0;`?

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar apenas < e também o valor não esta batendo. Preciso que thresh me retorne um valor inteiro para dividir pelos pixels depois. Apaguei o post com as imagens, obrigado por avisar!

Comment: Não uso o opencv pra ajudar mais, mas como o código é bem simples você pode rodar os dois programas em modo debug vendo o valor de `thresh` em ambos a cada iteração do loop mais interno.